# How to Determine Range Overlap within an Apache Spark RDD Using Python

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, rdd

I have an RDD that contains tuples of the form (label, min. value, max. value) where the values are integers.  For example:

(Label1, 1, 1000)
(Label2, 2, 999)
...
(LabelN, 3, 998)

I would like to iterate through this RDD to find which "ranges" fall within which other "ranges" as follows (where "range" is defined as the interval from min. value to max. value:

(Label1, 1, 1000) -> [Label2, LabelN]
 
(Label2, 2, 999)  -> [LabelN]
...
(LabelN, 3, 998)  -> []

I've checked a number of other questions but haven't been able to come up with a solution.

Comment: This is a bad problem formulation for distributed system, like Spark. Let's say, for the sake of argument, that you have `(_, -Inf, +Inf)`. This means you need _O(N)_ memory for each item in the worst case scenario. To make it feasible you have to put some restrictions, either on input, or output.

Comment: I do have restrictions/filters in place already but the question still stands.  If it somehow makes the question better feel free to pretend I'm trying to solve this question for N = 50 (or some other fixed value).

Comment: Sort data by min.value, scan each partition finding overlapping ranges, keep track of opened windows at the end of partition, perform second scan to fill the boundaries.

Comment: @zero323 That sounds pretty helpful thank you for your response.  I have nearly zero idea how to do that in Python though.  Is there any chance you can point me to a related example?  Thanks!

Comment: Think about the local problem first. Given a sorted sequence of events how do you determine overlaping events?  Simplify the problem first, by saying that you need `Record-I -> Label-J for each Record J that overlaps with Record I and I != J` (just keep track of "opened" events while traversing and check current event against all "opened" and yield matches.). Apply this to partitions. This will leave you with a bunch of opened ranges which have to be carried to the subsequent partition(-s) if `opened.max.value for opened in current_partition` > `next_partition.head.min.value`